# c# cant make more than one windows form?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I'm doing a windows application. I have form1 created for me, but now I want a form2, form3, etc. I tried the ways I know to create a new form under my project, but it directs me to create a new class. I right click the project and either choose: add new item (then choose window form, which it doesn't show up there for me) or "Form- Windows Form". When I click create new windows form, it directs me to create a new class and when I search windows form instead, it just won't show up.

Comment: this shouldn't happen.  project - add - form - form wrks fine here.

Comment: project - add new item?  it doesn't give me the option for a windows form. my tabs say... general and test settings

Comment: You right click on the project name in the Project Explorer pane. - Then  Either directly or add new item and pick from the list of installed items. If you have chosen a winforms project, you may want to repair the VS installation..

Comment: Are you in Visiual Studio or Visual Studio _Code_ ? Or some completely different IDE?

Comment: Sorry, Im using Visual Studio also it ended up being that I had to download .Net desktop development for it to finally allow me to add another form

Answer (score 0):

Your application have as default form Form1 usually.

[image]

Than you just right click on the project

Add--> New Item and a new window will appear

[image]

Select new Windows Form and press Add

After that you will have both forms on the solution

[image]

Now you can do it again for add others forms.
You should of course implement the logic of the forms and how open and show them.

For additional infos please take look to official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/forms/how-to-add?view=netdesktop-5.0)

Comment: I ended up not having the option until I downloaded the .Net desktop development from VS

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue.. without downloading the .Net desktop development from VS additions area I literally do not have that option. I wasn't able to provide screenshots yet so I couldn't show that but I can add another form now!